# EJB 3.0 and Future methods

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss6.x

We are using EJB 3.0 and I just read that Future methods will only work from 3.1 on. Is there a way to implement future methods in 3.0? We are using JBoss 6.4.9 as server application.

I have created the following method, which I call at the start of another method and at the end I need the response of this method.

```
@Asynchronous
private Future<COPCustomerDTO> getCustomerFromHostSystem(ServerEncryptedString aAccountNumber) {
    try {
        COPCustomerDTO copCustomerDTO = customerAccountFacade.getCustomerDTOByAdministrativeAccountNumber(aAccountNumber);
        return new AsyncResult<>(copCustomerDTO);
    } catch (CoPCommunicationException | InvalidExternalAccountReferenceException e) {
        throw new LogicRuntimeException("Unable to get COPCustomerDTO for customer", e);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not possible with standard Java EE. But some application servers have implemented extensions. What application server do you use?

Comment: We are using JBoss 6.4.9

Answer (score 0):

Good news :-) JBoss 6.4.x supports @Asynchronous

But your code will not work but @Asynchronous on a private method.
This only works for public methods because JBoss must create a proxy.

Comment: Ok, so the only thing I need to do is change the method to public?

Comment: I see that it's not the only thing that I need to change, a good description can be found here: http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/reference/build/reference/en/html_single/#d0e427

Comment: You always have to make methods public when using annotations because of the proxies. And you don't have to change anything else. JBoss 6.4 supports it out of the box.

Comment: Just a note: `@Asynchronous` will not work if invoked from within the same bean.